# How to split nodes evenly into groups with minimized number of edges between groups?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, grouping

I have a couple of nodes (e.g. 6 application servers) and edges (e.g. 10 direct information flows between those application servers). For a vizualization programming I want to programmatically split the nodes into 2 groups with even numbers of nodes efficiently, so that the groups have as low as possible number of edges between them. The actual nodes and edges are probably different everytime I run that vizualization routine.

An example...

Application Servers

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

InfoFlows

```
a->b
b->a
b->c
c->b
c->a
a->c
a->d
d->e
d->f
f->d
```

A potential solution would be:

group 1

```
a
b
c
a->b
b->a
b->c
c->b
c->a
a->c
```

group 2

```
d
e
f
d->e
d->f
f->d
```

link(s) between those groups:

```
a->d
```

Obviously I can build all possible combinations of groups and then count and compare. However that takes ages in cases where I have lots of nodes. So I am looking for a more clever solution which performs well and is reliable (so to say jump from the bubble sort like maturity to the class of quicksort). The coding itself is no issue - the question is more about the basic concept / algorithm.

Comment: global min-cut [problem](https://stanford.edu/~rezab/classes/cme305/W17/Notes/4.pdf)?

Comment: while that seems to be the name for my issue the source and other internet sources I found do not seem to really optimize for it - e.g. your source does not even exclude end and path nodes from global min cut considerations